# POST is Empty Array On Ajax Post Method

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, jquery-ajaxq

Using jquery ajax with Post method I have a code like

```
var col = senario +"_"+eTraget;
var data='column='+col;

$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"con/data.php",
    data:data,        
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (html) {
    coords = html;
    console.log(data);
})
```

now as you can see I used the console.log(data); and it print the result like `column=ce_3000`  in the console but in PHP file I have nothing in Array()!

```
<?php
define ( 'DB_HOST', 'localhost' );
define ( 'DB_USER', 'root' );
define ( 'DB_PASS', 'root' );
define ( 'DB_NAME', 'test' );
$col = $_POST['column'];

$con = new mysqli(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASS,DB_NAME);
$query = "SELECT x, y  FROM  ecoloprojects WHERE". $col."=1";

print_r($_POST);
$con->close();
?>
```

I tried to printr the POST array but it is empty can you please let me know why this is happening?

Update:

[image]

Comment: look in the developer console of your browser and see what is sent to the server

Comment: Hi Luke can you please let me know hoe to do that because in console I am not getting any thing!

Comment: there is a "network" tab where all the transfering between client and servers is logged

Comment: @jay I already have chrome console open that where I checked the console.log(data);

Comment: @Luke, there are bunch of columns and rows here how to see which one is the one?!

Comment: Change `console.log(data)` to `console.log(html)`. change `dataType: 'json'` to `dataType: 'html'` Put an error condition in your AJAX function. You're not sending or expecting to receive JSON at this point.

Comment: @jay, I update the result at post can you please take alook at that

Comment: See this? `Status Code:404 Not Found` That means that `con/data.php` isn't where you're looking for it to be. You will still need to make the other changes I suggested, plus putting the right path to the file.

Comment: Not sure if it is a copy/paste error but you are missing your closing `)` in your `$.ajax` function.

Comment: actually it is this happen after I change the code now I have the latest result can u please take a look at the update image

Comment: @jay, as you can see I have the data in the Array from Ajax side but looks like error is in PHP

Comment: Actually that looks like PHP output to me. What is in the response tab?

Comment: I have this Array
(
    [column] => ce_3000
)

Comment: Double check to make sure that the data isn't actually being sent to the `$_GET` variable. instead of the `$_POST` variable. I'm unfamiliar with the ajax method of jQuery, but i know that generally if my post values aren't there they sit in the `$_GET` variable and I have to work backward on why.

Comment: Good! @Behseini you're now making a successful request!

Comment: Thanks jhecht, but as you can see I am using Post methos!

Comment: @ Thanks Jay but I am not getting a successful response?

Comment: Did you change console.log as I advised?

Comment: I did but not getting any thing !

Comment: Nothing in the console? Since we're getting back a valid response that should appear in the console.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54663/discussion-between-behseini-and-jay-blanchard).

Comment: I cannot access chat from this location.

Comment: well not sure what to do then?

Comment: Is there any chance if you shadow my screen by Teamviewer?

Comment: then i will display what is happening exactly?

Comment: I have some restrictions here at work that don't allow me to do that. Post an image of your console output.

Comment: I think the problem that you have now is that your database query isn't working.

Comment: Exactly but when I hard coded  the $query like  $query = "SELECT x, y  FROM  ecoloprojects WHERE c_1000=1"; it wors perfectly

Comment: But when ever I have like this $query = "SELECT x, y  FROM  ecoloprojects WHERE".$col."=1"; it is not working!

Comment: As I said already this is because the $col = $_POST['column'];is empty!

Comment: What does the query return in MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

Try this in the JS instead:

```
var col = senario +"_"+eTraget;

$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"con/data.php",
    data:{column: col},        
    success: function (html) {
        coords = html;
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks hanleyhansen but same thing happening here again!

Comment: I am afraid but still smae!

Comment: jquery supports both strings or objects as data parameter. I think  the problem is on the php side.

Comment: @tehsis Good to know. I also added a brace he was missing unless he didn't copy the entire function in his OP.

Comment: Thanks but still I am not getting any thing in POST array

Comment: I updated the main post with an image from the Console Network